# Set the background color as the intensity of data in corrplot

Tags: r, matrix, r-corrplot

I have a matrix of data and I want to use the background color to show the value of the element of the matrix so the darker the background the bigger the matrix element. I have used corrplot like this:

```
corrplot(overlaps[[1]], method="number", is.corr=FALSE, type="full",
         cl.lim=c(0,100), addgrid.col="red", addshade="positive")
```

and the matrix would be like below:
[image]

But I want the background to show the intensity not the numbers as here. What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what about setting method to 'circle' or 'square'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(corrplot)
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)
corrplot(cor(m), method = "color", type="full", addgrid.col = "red",
        addshade = "positive", addCoef.col = "black")
```

Although I'm not sure if this is the best way to display correlations...

Comment: Thanks it works. But so what is your alternative solution to this if this is not the best.

Comment: I would use `method = "ellipse"` or `"circle"` and set `diag = TRUE`, since the diagonal is the least interesting information but is displayed most prominently in the plot. Also, you could set `addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0, alpha = 0.6)` for example, thereby the ellipses/circles are more prominent compared to the text.

Comment: I have one more question: how can I control the color intensity for example is I want to have dark red for the highest number and then decreasing and then for example have blue color for the lowest amount.

Comment: look at the documentation of the `col` argument in `?corrplot`. Default behavior is `corrplot(..., col = col2(200))`. To reverse the colorcode you just have to use `corrplot(..., col = rev(col2(200)))`. `col2`is a function that creates colors and is defined in the documentation of `corrplot`as well...